# Unknown key for a START_ARRAY in [fields]. in elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have been trying to get the specific fields data from the index that is been provided but getting the error "Unknown key for a START_ARRAY in [fields]".

Unknown key for a START_ARRAY in [fields].

fields: ['snippet.publishedAt']

my expected output out is it should provide the fields array in the hits

Answer (score 35):

You should be using [`stored_fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-stored-fields) or [`_source`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-source-filtering) instead of `fields`, i.e.

```
stored_fields: ['snippet.publishedAt']
```

or

```
_source: ['snippet.publishedAt']
```

**UPDATE:**

From 7.10 onwards, a new [fields features](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/search-fields.html#search-fields-param) is now available.

Comment: Elastic 7.10 introduced new [Fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/search-fields.html#search-fields-param) feature. One can use this feature now to retrieve specific fields and the error in question should not occur.

Answer (score 5):

For ES7.3 (current version as writing) you can pass a `_source` field which can contain a comma separated list of fields.

```
_source: 'snippet.publishedAt'
```

You can read more about this [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html#docs-get-api-query-params)